# What's the convention for the symbols of enthalpies of formation, reaction, etc.?

Tags: notation

I frequently encounter two ways of writing enthalpies of some process, e.g. for the enthalpy of formation:

1. $\Delta_{r} G$ (or $\Delta_{R} G$)
2. $\Delta G_{r}$ (or $\Delta G_{R}$)

On the IUPAC Gold Book webpage they used the first notation (although the use of upper- and lower-case descriptors varies, see [here](http://goldbook.iupac.org/I03313.html) and [here](http://goldbook.iupac.org/GT07388.html)). Is this the accepted way of doing it (and the other one is simply a relic) or might this be a matter of preference. And how about the upper- or lower-case descriptor: Is there any convention for that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you have already answered your question… IUPAC's usage should be a pretty good indicator of the proper notation.

There is, however, an even better reference than the Gold Book: **IUPAC's [Green Book](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantities,_Units_and_Symbols_in_Physical_Chemistry), or *Quantities, Units and Symbols in Physical Chemistry*** ([full text here](http://www.iupac.org/fileadmin/user_upload/publications/e-resources/ONLINE-IUPAC-GB3-2ndPrinting-Online-Sep2012.pdf)), on section 2.11.1 Other symbols and conventions in chemical thermodynamics (page 59 and following):

> (iii) Examples of the use of the symbol ∆
>   The symbol ∆ denotes a change in an extensive thermodynamic quantity for a process. The addition of a subscript to the ∆ denotes a change in the property.

It says later:

> [∆<sub>vap</sub>*H*] can also be written ∆*H*<sub>vap</sub>, but **this usage is not recommended**

The reason is that ∆*H*<sub>vap</sub> could be understand as a change in *H*<sub>vap</sub>, which it is not. It a change of *H* during a process, so the subscript should be on the ∆.

Comment: Thanks for making me aware of the Green Book. I shouldn't have stopped looking after finding the Gold Book.